# UIButtons not working on certain devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I've set up a view and constraints using the wAny hAny layout in Xcode 6:

[image]

When I run the app on a iPhone 5s and iPhone 6 the UI Elements are all visible but on the 5s the `answer` and the `back` buttons do not work - they do nothing.

On the iPhone 6 all the buttons work.

Here's the code for the `back' button:

```
- (IBAction)backFromDivision:(id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The `answer` code is a bit longer and I won't post it unless necessary.

Does this have something to do with the constraints or should I be looking for answers elsewhere?

Comment: Interesting problem - on the 5S, which doesn't work, do the buttons show the usual colour change when touched? - i.e. do the buttons function from a visual perspective?

Comment: They do not function at all. Visually or programmatically.

Comment: Then I believe this relates to the constraints. Can you try with auto layout disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

I clicked on "Resolve Auto Layout Issues" - "Reset to suggested constraints" (third from the left):

[image]

and that "solved" my problem.  Everything is working on all devices.  It seems to have removed some constraints that I put in place.

I'm going to have to learn more about why this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue before. It was the constraints that were the issue and the fact that the button was not in the view's bounds.

Comment: If it's not in the views bounds then why is it visible on the screen?

Comment: Not the main view, the subview I mean.

Comment: Just ran into similar issue today. I have a view designed in a XIB file. It has 2 text fields and a button. I changed the container view's autoresizing constraints by enabling all springs/struts. Everything still *looked* fine on all devices, but the button no longer responded to taps on smaller screens (iPhone 5, 5s, etc...). I backed out my changes to the container view's autoresizing properties, and that fixed it. Apparently the tappable area does not always align with the visible area? Strange.

Comment: @ShawnFlahave That's exactly it

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this issue, and the problem was due to the button having:

**buttonView.frame.height = 0.**    (it can also happen with width)

The problem is that even with no height the button text appears on screen so if you don't have a background **the button visual appearance does not change**.

To resolve this issue I played with the views Content Compression Resistance Priority(CCRP) of different views to chose which view should resize on smaller screen.

The default CCRP of views is 750, default contraint priority  is  1000.
 So to match your constraint ios may resize the height of your views